# Access Firebase User From Multiple Pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to access a firebase authentication user from multiple pages. I tried this on 1.html, 2.html, and code.js. 1.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.0/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="email" id="email">
        <input type="password" id="password">
        <button onclick="sign()">Yo</button>
    </body>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</html>
```

2.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.0/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="p" onload="runIt()">TEST</p>
    </body>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</html>
```

CODE.JS

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
function sign() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
        window.location = "2.html";
    });
}
function runIt() {
   console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
}
```

How would I be able to log, in the console, the user's uid from the second page? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are loading the shared [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls) and firebase config file on both pages being served from the same domain/ipaddr. An authorization token is granted and persists as configured. Every new page load results in a state change, `.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`

[Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

> You can specify how the Authentication state persists when using the
>   Firebase JS SDK. This includes the ability to specify whether a signed
>   in user should be indefinitely persisted until explicit sign out,
>   cleared when the window is closed or cleared on page reload.

[Expected behavior across browser tabs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#expected_behavior_across_browser_tabs)

> The following expected behavior will apply when different persistence
>   types are used in different tabs. The requirement is that at any
>   point, there should never be multiple types of saved states at the
>   same time (eg. auth state saved in session and local types of
>   storage):
>
> - Users can sign in using session or none persistence with different users on multiple tabs. Each tab cannot see the state of the other
>     tab.
> - Any attempt to sign in using local persistence will be detected and synchronized on all tabs. If the user was previously signed in on a
>     specific tab using session or none persistence, that state will be
>     cleared.
> - If the user was previously signed in using local persistence with multiple tabs opened and then switches to none or session persistence
>     in one tab, the state of that tab will be modified with the user
>     persisted in session or none and on all other tabs, the user will be
>     signed out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
  uid = user.uid; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happened is it called the function before it signed in the user. You have to give it a second. You can write:

```
function initApp() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
        }
    });
}
```

Then, it will log the uid after there is a change in the auth state, or when the user signs in.